# Get list of recently messaged users from Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have two models, named users and messages. It's basically a chat application. The models are associated as below:

```
User.hasMany(Message);
Message.belongsTo(User);

User-> id, name, pic
Message-> id, text, timestamp, user_id (foreign key)
```

I want to get a **list of users who has recently messaged**. Here is what I've tried:

```
DB.User.findAll({
 include: [{
  model: DB.Message,
  order: [
   ['timestamp', 'DESC']
  ],
  limit: 1
 }]
});
```

The SQL Query may look like this:

> SELECT U.first_name, user_id, MAX(timestamp) FROM messages M, users
>   U WHERE M.user_id=U.id GROUP BY user_id

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DB.User.findAll({
 include: [ { model: DB.Message, required: true,order:['id','DESC']}]
});
```

Comment: Not working. It will sort all message, but won't sort users